# Flatlist with search, onEndReached is not called when search return 0 results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist which fetch data from a remote server, the flatlist have pagination implemented and a linked search functionality.
OnEndReached is called when I hit the end of the list and the next page is loaded, the same thing happen when I search through the list and one or more record is found that matchs the search criteria.
However when I search through the list and there is 0 result matching the search from the already loaded records, in this case onEndReached is not called at all.
I tried different value for the onendreachedthreshold but prop without success.
Do you have any idea why is this happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onEndReached` is called when the end of the view of the FlatList is within the range of the `onEndReachedThreshold`.

In the case where 0 results are displayed, the view of the FlatList would be within the visible screen area (i.e. no scrolling), hence, `onEndReached` won't be called. That's how `onEndReached` works.

P.S. If you're trying to display a message when 0 results are displayed, you should try calling it when the results are fetched and the page 1 is empty. Since I don't exactly know what you're trying to do, I can't suggest you the best solution. Try explaining a bit more maybe.